# HTML Output from DB Issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, output

I am running a CKEditor TextArea WYSIWYG field through `htmlspecialchars()` and dumping it into a database.

I am then fetching the field in the database and it's outputting HTML to the screen.  Any reason why it is outputting the HTML and not actually utilizing the HTML for markup?

**CODE FOR THE DATA DUMP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $ticketBody = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ticketBody']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (ticket_text) VALUES(:ticketBody)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ticketBody', $ticketBody, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

**LOOPING THROUGH THE DATA**

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    <?php echo $row['ticket_text']; ?>
}
```

**Screencast of Output:** http://screencast.com/t/wbUUS3OrW

**NOTE:** Adding `htmlspecialchars_decode` to my `echo` statement works but turns my text white!  Which I'm not sure why, either - http://screencast.com/t/JgJMaoCdyuTM

`strip_tags()` function doesn't work either.

Comment: can you post the resultant html code? after of decode

Comment: I take it that HTML tags are automatically being inserted somehow. If so, you can prevent it and use PHP/CSS to format it after. I don't know CKEditor, so I couldn't say for certain as to why it would be doing, if CKE is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

Use **mysqli_real_scape_string** instead of **html_special_chars** this will maintain your html code anda specials chars while your database keep safe, in the next link you can found documentation if this.

[For you security don't click here, never!!](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: *"Use mysqli_real_scape_string"* - OP is using PDO and doesn't need to use that, since they're using prepared statements. Using what you say, would be considered as mixing MySQL APIs, which you can't do.

Comment: @Jjsg08 - I'm using PDO.  That doesn't apply here.

Comment: *"For you security don't click here, never!!"* - Huh?! do modify this or delete it before you get downvoted.

Comment: In this case only avoid the use of **html_special_chars**

Comment: @Fred-ii- Its only is a funny appoinment ;)

Comment: I have a sense of humour also ;-) however, others may not. Your answer as it stands, doesn't hold true. Not with *"Use mysqli_real_scape_string"*